# How to place lines between columns using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]How to place lines between columns. This is the below code i am working on but still not working. is there any way we can add separator? i added the screen shot what i am expecting.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid controls">
  <div class="container">
    <form   class="form-form-submit">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *"
              required="required" data-error="name is required.">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
            <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Please enter your phone number">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="btn-group"  style="padding-top: 25px;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Expecting to place this code to show lines:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
<div class="line">|</div>
<div>OR</div> 
<div class="line">|</div>
</div>
```

I want output like this.

```
                 |
Name             | Email
                OR
Phone  Button    |
                 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do.

```css
.v-line {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.or {
  background-color: #e9ecef;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid controls">
  <div class="container">
    <form   class="form-form-submit">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="d-inline-block w-50">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
              <input id="form_name" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *"
                required="required" data-error="name is required.">
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
              <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control"
                placeholder="Please enter your phone number">
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="v-line d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <span class="or">OR</span>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-block w-50">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
              <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              <div class="btn-group"  style="padding-top: 25px;">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: v-line is working fine. but i want to add "OR" between vertical line. <div class="line">|</div>
<div>OR</div> 
<div class="line">|</div>

Comment: I have edited my answer but there may have a better way to do it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. is it possible to  place "Submit" button next to phone number text box with padding"?

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink the fields by one `col` unit, so that both the left and right fields are `col-md-5`. This will give them a total column span of `10`, leaving `2` spare (as Bootstrap columns always total `12`).

From here, you can add `offset-md-2` to the right-most columns to create a gap composed of 2 columns:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid controls">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-form-submit">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *" required="required" data-error="name is required.">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
            <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone number">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-2">
          <div class="btn-group" style="padding-top: 25px;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Note that you cannot (easily) make the gap comprise of only 1 unit while keeping both columns the same length (as the total column count is even). However, you can make use of any combination of column + offset + column that *totals* twelve. For example, `col-md-5` + `offset-md-1` + `col-md-6`.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a better way to do this but right now this is I can remember. Basically, just create an empty col div in between the two columns:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid controls">
  <div class="container">
    <form   class="form-form-submit">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5"`enter code here`>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *"
              required="required" data-error="name is required.">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
            <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
            <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Please enter your phone number">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="btn-group"  style="padding-top: 25px;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```